# In mongo using new ObjectId from c# for a property other than _id

Tags: c#, mongodb

In mongo shell I can do the following

```
db.getCollection('tests').update({"Name":"Test"},{"$set": {"Val": ObjectId()}},{upsert: true})
```

And if no record exists with a property named `Name`, it will create a new record with three properties (`_id`, `Name`, `Val`). And the value of `Val` will be an `ObjectId` which is created on mongo side.

Can I do the same thing from c#? I want the value of `Val` created on mongo side.

Comment: Something like `Builders<SomeClass>.Update.Set(e => e.Val, new ObjectId())`

Comment: @Veeram Is this going to use the time of the mongo server or the c# server? I want it to be created on mongo side.

Comment: This will be on client side, just like all the ids. If you really wanted to genrated this one id on server side you can see this answer stackoverflow.com/questions/24723954/…

Comment: @Veeram That is for "_id". I want the same thing for another property, i.e. "Val". My use case is more complicated than the one in the question.